# Database design for complex requirement

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a table for ticket type, (like new,update,escalate), and they have subtypes (for example new have around 5 subtypes eg. server,access etc).

Now every subtype have different info to be stored..(subtype server needs start date, end date, server name and access needs customer id,access type,confirmation attachment etc).

Basically, every subtype will require diff no.of info... so i want to ask , whether i should create diff table for each subtype...for Server i create a table with 4 column and for access i create a table with 7 col.

Chances are low new subtypes will be required once deployed, but still a possibility, so a new table will be created...

Is going this way the correct thing to do, or any other method is there?

Comment: This question is too vaguely formulated to answer.

Comment: i am not sure how to put this then...is it correct to create a new table for every subtype because they have different info to be stored..or a better way exists

Answer (score 0):

Whether you should create a new table for each subtype depends on the nature of the inheritence. The following rule of thumb applies:

> MANDATORY; AND:  1 Table for superclass + all subclasses
>
> MANDATORY; OR: 1 Table for each subclass
>
> OPTIONAL; AND: 1 Table for the superclass, 1 table for all subclasses
>
> OPTIONAL; OR: 1 Table for superclass, 1 table for each subclass

MANDATORY means: every member of the superclass must be a member of a subclass.

AND means: a member of the superclass can be several subtypes

Calculated example: let's say you have a model that contains 1 superclass and 3 subclasses.

The total number of tables you would get for each of the four types of inheritence is respectively: 1, 3, 2, 4